# Highcharts on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am quite new to Rails, and I need to work on a report generating plugin using Rails and Highcharts for the output. My main issue is that my user is meant to be able to define a time range using a jQuery datepicker. How can I get the highcharts graph on the x axis to reflect the time range based on the users selection, and how do I tie it to the other fields in the rails model.

Eg. If I have a table with a `created_by` field which the user is supposed to pick his to and from dates from... and the table also has `user_id` and the users select a specific language for each application. I want the graph to show for each day the count of the different languages different users selected during their application.

Hope my question is clear enough. Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of parts involved here (date pickers, queries, highcharts rendering). Better help could be provided with a more specific question. Perhaps you may need to make several questions out of this one?

Comment: i have been able to work on the datepicker bit of the application, but i need to understand i the two dates he picks can be used to form the array that gives me the date range for the highcharts x axis

Answer (score 4):

You should look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts